# iOS Swift app random EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash: swift_bridgeObjectRetain swift_retain swift::RefCounts<swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1>

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I keep getting random crash reports from random users. Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce this on my end on a regular basis. Users say that the crash happens randomly in the `DiscussionViewController`. All crash reports have this similar:

```
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a53face4 swift::RefCounts<swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1> >::incrementSlow(swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1>, unsigned int) + 60 (atomic:1003)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a53c59e0 swift_retain + 124 (RefCount.h:813)
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a5401d60 swift_bridgeObjectRetain + 56 (SwiftObject.mm:585)
3   APPNAME                             0x0000000102b59734 closure #1 in DiscussionViewController.fetchPostData() + 7916
```

Here's the full crash log and the thread which crashed:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,6
Process:             APPNAME [11770]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../APPNAME.app/APPNAME
Identifier:          ----
Version:             62 (62)
AppStoreTools:       12E262
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,6:13
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ---- [1824]


Date/Time:           2021-06-17 12:07:01.4346 +1000
Launch Time:         2021-06-17 12:06:56.4993 +1000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.04.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x8000000000000010 -> 0x0000000000000010 (possible pointer authentication failure)
VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4339515376
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   102a7c000-102a94000 [   96K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...APPNAME.app/APPNAME

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [11770]
Triggered by Thread:  3


Thread 3 name:
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a53face4 swift::RefCounts<swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1> >::incrementSlow(swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1>, unsigned int) + 60 (atomic:1003)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a53c59e0 swift_retain + 124 (RefCount.h:813)
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a5401d60 swift_bridgeObjectRetain + 56 (SwiftObject.mm:585)
3   APPNAME                             0x0000000102b59734 closure #1 in DiscussionViewController.fetchPostData() + 7916
4   APPNAME                             0x0000000102ad09d4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Data?, @guaranteed NSURLResponse?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 132 (<compiler-generated>:0)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a1b0a3dc __40-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClassInfo:]_block_invoke + 540 (LocalSession.mm:687)
6   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a1b1c768 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 244 (LocalSessionTask.mm:584)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a10d1a84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1466)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a10d381c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a10db004 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620 (inline_internal.h:2557)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a10dbc34 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 456 (queue.c:3862)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a10e64bc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764 (queue.c:6589)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ed04a7a4 0x1ed047000 + 14244
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ed05174c 0x1ed047000 + 42828
```

I have verified that the `DiscussionViewController.fetchPostData()` is not force unwrapping any optionals, doesn't have `try!` and is using `[weak self]` and `self?` everywhere. The function is pretty big so I am having a hard time narrowing down where the crash is occurring.

Comment: "Users say that the crash happens randomly in the DiscussionViewController."  Okay, show the code, then.

Comment: The `DiscussionViewController.fetchPostData()` is quite long. Can't the stack trace give me a hint of where exactly the crash is coming from and then I can post that narrow code?

Comment: That depends on the cause of the crash.

Comment: A fully symbolicated crash log should show line numbers too, but I don’t have much experience with these. It’s also just good to make short functions in general.

Comment: If you are using `URLSessionConfiguration`, you'd better be careful not to let the app create its object repeatedly.

Comment: For general discussion, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/investigating-memory-access-crashes